# Vectorising matlab function

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization, trigonometry

I'm writing a function to get the cosine of a given array. It works but I'm presently using a loop in order to iterate over each value in the array whereas I'm assured that it can be vectorised.

Presently the code is:

```
for i = 1:numel(x)
    cos(i) = (sum(((-1).^(0:n)).*(x(i).^(2*(0:n)))./(factorial(2*(0:n)))));
end
```

and I can't for the life of me think how it vectorises, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the full function http://pastebin.com/n1DG6nUv

2nd EDIT: link updated with new code that doesn't overwrite cos.

Comment: what is n, what is x? x seems to be a ax1 vector?

Comment: The code you linked to allocates a matrix `fcos`, but doesn't use it. Instead the data is put into an unallocated array `cos`, overwriting the `cos` function. Typo?

Comment: @DanielR it could be anything vector, scalar or matrices

Comment: @horchler yes, that would appear to be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`gamma`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gamma.html):

```
v = 0:n;
fcos = zeros(size(x));
fcos(:) = sum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@power,x(:),2*v),(-1).^v./gamma(2*v+1)),2)
```

In the spirit of learning, note that you have several issues with the code in your question. First, you don't preallocate memory. Second, you're overwriting the `cos` function, which is probably not a good idea. Also, I believe that using `gamma(n+1)` instead of `factorial(n)` will be faster. Finally, there are many unnecessary parentheses that make the code hard to read.

Comment: I've added a link to my full code.
I actually am preallocating the memory, it just isn't in the snippet that I originally posted.
hmm, yeah I guess I am overwriting the cos function; that wasn't intentional....
I don't know anything about the gamma function but, if you think it'll be faster, I'll look into it.

x could actually be anything: vector, scalar, matrices, etc.
You're right, though, I might well need to use the reshape function.